# TimerTrigger not triggering after start of function app

Tags: azure, azure-functions, timer-trigger

I am trying to create a very simple TimerTriggered function to prevent my app from getting cold.

The issue is that after deploying the app or after restarting it the TimerTriggered function is never executed. After invoking the function manually the timer starts running as expected.

Some info that might be useful:

- My app has a mix of different triggers.
- The runtime version used is 2.0.11651.0.
- The app service plan has a consumption plan and has to stay that way.
- In this case I deploy using Visual Studio

My class looks like the following:

```
public static class KeepAliveTask
{
    [FunctionName("KeepAlive")]
    public static void Run([TimerTrigger("0 */4 * * * *", RunOnStartup = true)]TimerInfo timer, TraceWriter log)
    {
        log.Info("Keeping service alive");
    }
}
```

That's all there is to it. I've been searching but has been unable to find anyone with the same problem. Any suggestions is appreciated.

Comment: How are you deploying the function app?

Comment: See whether this [github issue](https://github.com/Azure/Azure-Functions/issues/210) helps.

Comment: @PaulBatum At this stage I am deploying directly from Visual Studio.

Comment: @JerryLiu Thanks for the link. I don't think the issue is releated to the function not being synced, as it usually are when I deploy through Visual Studio. Also I do see my TimerTriggered function listed in the Azure portal.

Comment: @Casper Can't repro on my side(consumption plan, same runtime, VS deploy). I checked my log files, it starts once deployed or restarted.

Comment: Have you tried to deploy this timertrigger to a new(empty) function app?

Comment: @JerryLiu I tried to deploy my whole application to another app service. I still have the same issue. I then tried to create a whole new app service and deploy a new project only containing the timertrigger - that one seems to work. I am confused. Nothing should break when mixing different triggers in one app, right?

Comment: I can take a further look if you can share the details discussed here: https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/wiki/Sharing-Your-Function-App-name-privately

Comment: @PaulBatum Thanks for wanting to help out. The time and id is from a function app in which I reproduced the issue. I triggered the timer function and grabbed it from insights. Time: 2018-06-11T07:56:48.7069142+00:00 Id: 14837d17-7112-443e-b895-e2e82596608a

Comment: @PaulBatum Any updates?